# Can SoC Processors be used as more powerful microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, soc

I'm starting with microcontrollers (still avr), and once I finish, I'll be moving on to ARM based microcontrollers.

However, as I've been reading, the ARM Cortex M is basically the best you can get, like for example the ARM Cortex-M7 based smt32, which runs at 300MHz max.

Which is a lot, but say if I want use a touch LCD control panel that shows the weather, current temperature (which then controls the A/C), the currently active systems in the house (lights, etc), and connects to the house speaker system to play music from its (external) media library. Then Cortex M series wouldn't be the right choice. (Would it?)

The Cortex A series as I read, is the more powerful design, which some companies use to build SoC chips, which are more powerful everything-on-a-chip processing units. (Right?)

Are any of these Cortex A based SoCs available to the public or are they made by big companies for their own specific design only? What would be a solution for the system I plan on making?

By the way, I know something similar could probably be bought, but I'm trying to build this myself as a starting ground.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that needs lots of CPU power, unless you plan to run some PC OS on it. Of course Cortex A are available outside SoC. Did you even check pretty much any silicon vendor's website?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Comment: I suspect that even an ARM Cortex M7 may not be the right choice if you want to leverage from the Linux code base, as it lacks memory management hardware.

Comment: If you find you need more horsepower but don't want to go the the (significant) effort of designing & building fancy PCBs with BGA micros & SDRAM you should consider a 'COM' like those from [gumstix](https://store.gumstix.com/coms.html) for example.

Comment: @DaveTweed I coined the phrase the "Engineering-Null Hypothesis" as these "can it be done?" questions were commonly part of the research done around the lab and being proposed in research grants. That framing gave the questions a more solid standing among the science-minded peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU may not be the limiting factor for your project.
You need a controller which has the necessary peripherals onboard, i.e. external memory interfaces (or enough internal memory), a video interface, maybe a GPU, ...

> Then Cortex M series wouldn't be the right choice. (Would it?)

Depends on your requirements (display resolution, etc.). I'm not sure about that music thing, but controlling a VGA display and doing some less complex, not time critical tasks, even a PIC24 could be enough.

Cypress' new Traveo II family will have a Cortex-M7 inside, but to be honest, even the existing Traveo family with Cortex-R5 should by far satisfy your requirements.

NXP's i.Mx6 series may be an alternative, if you want to go with Cortex-A.

> Are any of these Cortex A based SoCs available to the public or are
>   they made by big companies for their own specific design only?

Of course they are available. But take into account that designing a system with such a controller is not trivial.
You have to deal with high speed external memories and BGA packages... a lot of design and layout rules to consider - and as a single person you won't get support of the manufacturer.

> By the way, I know something similar could probably be bought, but I'm
>   trying to build this myself as a starting ground.

If it's really just one device for your own use: Raspberry Pi would probably be the best and fastest way to get what you want.
You still want to make your own Cortex-A PCB? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks available to me: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.uk/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microprocessors/694?FV=ffe002b6&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&k=cortex-a&pageSize=25&pkeyword=cortex-a). Parametric search is your friend.

Note that they tend to come in less convenient packages and not have integrated RAM, so your PCB design is a lot harder.

Note also that a 300MHz RISC processor can actually do quite a lot; that's roughly equivalent to a desktop computer of the late 90s. The only thing in your list that might be tricky is music decoding, and you can usually farm that off to a dedicated MP3/AAC decoder chip if you want. Or get it sent over the network in decompressed form. Certainly the web is full of people driving small touch panel weather station projects from Arduinos. Or the ever-present Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The STM32F4 discovery boards have codecs on board.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the page in digikey, I got my answer. Also, as i said I'm new to this, so letting me know 300MHz would be more than enough also cleared part of my mind. I'll continue with avr, then move to cortex M. If needed ill use an already made setup for the higher end projects in the future (if ever needed).